# getXml(id) - Resource not found exception

Tags: android, android-layout

My target is to apply style on individual `View`s. I've created a style in `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="trLinearLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

the corresponding `ID` is generated in `R.java` and the following code is using the above style:

```
    XmlResourceParser parser =    context.getResources().getXml(R.style.apptheme_black);
    AttributeSet attribs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

    LinearLayout tr = new LinearLayout(context, attribs);
```

I get following exception while running:

```
04-10 16:41:52.053: W/ResourceType(283): Requesting resource 0x7f050005 failed because it is complex
04-10 16:41:52.065: W/System.err(283): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050005
04-10 16:41:52.065: W/System.err(283):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
04-10 16:41:52.065: W/System.err(283):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1865)
04-10 16:41:52.065: W/System.err(283):  at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:779)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is R.style.apptheme_black?

Comment: its defined in res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

**getXml** method is used for fetching xml resources out from **res/xml** folder.

Comment: I read somewhere that AttributeSet is the way to apply styles to Views (pass in constructor) and this is how I create an AttributeSet.

Comment: can you include that reference material in your question too?